# Testing AutoCompleteTextView with Espresso

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, android-espresso, testing-support-library

I am using Espresso to test an app with several AutoCompleteTextViews. For one particular test, the autocomplete popup appears, but I want to just ignore it and move to the next `TextView`. How can I do this? My ideas are to either simulate a "Back" press or simulate a tap in the popup.

**Update:**

I am attempting the following to click on the autocomplete popup:

```
onView(withId(R.id.brand_text))
        .perform(scrollTo(), typeText(card.getBrand()));
onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(String.class)), is(card.getBrand())))
        .inRoot(isPlatformPopup())
        .perform(click());
onView(withId(R.id.brand_text))
        .check(matches(withText(card.getBrand())));
```

Now the problem is that in some cases, the text entered doesn't have any autocomplete matches so no popup appears. How do I conditionally perform the click depending on whether or not a view is matched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to add a `UiDevice` object from UI Automator to my test:

```
 UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
```

Then I call `UiDevice.pressEnter()` to advance to the next `TextView`.

```
device.pressEnter();
```

The problem encountered is that this doesn't work as expected out of the box. I also added a `View.OnKeyListener` to each `AutoCompleteTextView` to handle the Enter key event. For now I add a listener to each view and explicitly state which view requests focus on an Enter key event.

```
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...

    brandText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() { 
        @Override 
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) { 
                yearText.requestFocus(); 
                return true; 
            } 

            return false; 
        } 
    });

    //...
}
```

This isn't ideal. Eventually I plan to generalize this, possibly with a custom component which inherits from `AutoCompleteTextView` which handles the Enter key as I expect. It will send focus to the "next" view.